# Inno Setup: Capture control events in wizard page

Tags: inno-setup

In a user defined wizard page, is there a way to capture change or focus events of the controls? I want to provide an immediate feedback on user input in some dropdowns (e.g. a message box)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took me some time to work it out, but after being pointed in the right direction by Otherside, I finally got it (works for version 5.2):

```
[Code]

var 
    MyCustomPage : TWizardPage;

procedure MyEditField_OnChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
    MsgBox('TEST',  mbError, MB_OK);
end;

function MyCustomPage_Create(PreviousPageId: Integer): Integer;
var 
    MyEditField: TEdit;
begin
    MyCustomPage := CreateCustomPage(PreviousPageId, 'Caption', 'Description');
    MyEditField  := TEdit.Create(MyCustomPage);
    MyEditField.OnChange := @MyEditField_OnChange;
end;
```

Comment: Can you add the version of Inno Setup that you are using this code with?  It looks like version 5.  I ask this because I know there is quite a lot of difference regarding custom pages between versions 4 and 5.

Comment: Hi Otherside, I added the version number to my answer. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Since the scripting in innosetup is loosely based on Delphi, the controls should have some events like `OnEnter` (= control got focus) and `OnExit` (= control lost focus).  You can assign procedures to these events, something like this:
    ComboBox.OnExit := ComboBoxExit;

```
procedure ComboBoxExit(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;
```

I don't have access to Innosetup right now, so you will need to lookup the available events and parameters for the procedures.